# I want to convert this query from mssql to mysql

Tags: mysql, sql-server, procedure

```
  CREATE PROC spGetAdmin

    @UserName nvarchar(50)
  AS 
SELECT * FROM Admin WHERE UserName=@UserName
```

Comment: I created table admin in mysql, am trying to get the equivalent of the above question in mysql code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE spGetAdmin
(
IN User_Name VARCHAR(50)
)
BEGIN
   SELECT * FROM Admin WHERE UserName=User_Name;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: giving me this error:  You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'END' at line 7
Line 2, column 1

Answer (score 0):

Check this link to create procedure in mysql.

[CREATE PROCEDURE IN MYSQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html)

Here as reference suggest your query should be like following.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spGetAdmin 
(
   IN UserName varchar(64)
) 
BEGIN 
    SELECT * FROM Admin WHERE UserName=UserName;
END;
```

Thanks..

Comment: giving me error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') 
BEGIN 
    SELECT * FROM Admin WHERE UserName=UserName
END' at line 4

Comment: @user3405662 There should not be a comma after `varchar(64)`.